# Sys.Indexes items are missing from sys.objects view SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have just installed SQL Server 2014.

- Product: Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
- Platform: NT x64
- Version: 12.0.2000.8
- Server Collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS
- Is Clustered: False
- Is HADR Enabled: False

I created a database using right click on Databases --> New Database. I set a name, I left the default options and I pressed OK.

Executing the following query, I realized that there are items from `sys.indexes` view that cannot be found in `sys.objects`.

```
Select * 
From sys.indexes ind
Where not exists ( select * from sys.objects obj where ind.object_id = obj.object_id )
```

The above query returns the following results:

```
5575058         plan_persist_plan_cidx
5575058         plan_persist_plan_idx1
21575115        plan_persist_runtime_stats_cidx
21575115        plan_persist_runtime_stats_idx1
37575172        plan_persist_runtime_stats_interval_cidx
37575172        plan_persist_runtime_stats_interval_idx1
53575229        plan_persist_context_settings_cidx
2121058592      plan_persist_query_text_cidx
2121058592      plan_persist_query_text_idx1
2137058649      plan_persist_query_cidx
2137058649      plan_persist_query_idx1
```

I read that non schema-scoped items are not returned from `sys.objects` view, but I cannot find any information related to the above items. Until today I used SQL Server 2012 and I didn't have any problem with the above table connection logic.

What kind of items are these?

How can I distinguish these items from other (other=the items returned from `sys.objects`)?

Thanks,
Kostas

Comment: Do you have any idea, why the above is happening? 

I can handle that case in my code, just i don't know if that is possible to happen in other cases as well.

I would to be prepared before upgrading to SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude these items by checking the IsMsShipped object property:

```
Select * 
From sys.indexes ind
Where not exists ( select * from sys.objects obj where ind.object_id = obj.object_id )
And objectproperty( ind.object_id, 'IsMSShipped' ) = 0
```